# Join rows of table A with columns of table B in MySQL

Tags: mysql, join, database-design, relational

I have two tables, A and B.

Table A contains a list of samples, which are numbered, but also have character id. It has the form

```
sample_num    sample_id  
1              id_1   
2              id_2
.              .
.              .
.              .
n              id_n
```

Table B contains gene expression data for each sample. It has the form

```
probe_num     1   2 . . . n    
1            
2
.
.
.
m
```

Ideally I would have samples as rows, and the genes as columns, however, there are too many genes for MySQL to store as columns so I cannot really change this.

Now, I am given a subset of sample id's and asked to return the associated gene expression data. But I can't figure out how to perform the required join. I need to join on the column *identifiers* from table B with the sample_num column from table A.

This would be easy if I could, for instance, transpose table B, but I don't know if this is possible or not given the limitation on the number of columns.

Comment: You should have a junction table with one row per probe and expression.  Storing "arrays" of data in separate columns is generally a bad idea.

Comment: So ...what's the exact (and fixed) structure of table B? What fields does it have? When you refer to column 'identifiers' you mean a field with that name, or it refers to field 1, or field 2, or...?

Comment: @MarcM The fields correspond to the entries of the sample_num column of table A. The structure of table B isn't fixed actually, which I guess is a bad thing. If a new sample is added, a new column is added to table B, and a new row is added to table A.

Comment: It sounds like I need to follow @Gordon 's advice and use junction tables, but I don't know what they are yet so I best go away and learn about them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding what you say in a comment:

> The structure of table B isn't fixed actually, which I guess is a bad thing. If a new sample is added, a new column is added to table B, and a new row is added to table A.

Clearly, this is a bad relational design.

Instead, I suggest you to use a different aproach (the one used for n:m relationships)

```
Table B
probe_num gene_num gene_value
1         1        value_for_gene_1_of_probe_1
1         2        value_for_gene_2_of_probe_1
1         3        value_for_gene_3_of_probe_1
1         4        value_for_gene_4_of_probe_1
...and so on for probe_1
2         1        value_for_gene_1_of_probe_2
2         2        value_for_gene_2_of_probe_2
2         3        value_for_gene_3_of_probe_2
2         4        value_for_gene_4_of_probe_2
```

Now you can store information of different genes for differents probes. If new data related to new genes appears, there's no need to modify data structure. Just add new lines to the table. Such as

```
probe_num gene_num gene_value
15        2714     value_for_gene_2714_of_probe_15
```

Your table will probably have lots of lines (not a problem!)

For getting all gene information related to the probe 15:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_B
WHERE probe_num = 15;
```

Finally, you can relate it with table A as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_B
JOIN TABLE_A ON TABLE_A.sample_num = TABLE_B.sample_num
WHERE TABLE_A.sample_id LIKE 'id_2';
```